# Possible to authenticate/retrieve user on intranet when set to Forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have an asp.net MVC application that will be running on our company's intranet.  I want to retrieve the logged on/windows identity of the user in lieu of a login page.  Using Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name and running on my local Visual Studio (ASP.Net Development Server), I am able to retrieve the user's domain/username.  When published to my intranet webserver(IIS 7), I am only able to retrieve the username of the service my app pool is running under.  Is it possible, using Forms authentication, for me to be able to retrieve the logged in user?  Many of the discussions I have found suggest switching to Windows authentication...which is not an option for me at this point.  My current authentication is forms:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>`
```

my IIS has Anonymous, Impersonation, and Forms authentication enabled.

Comment: I'd recommend *never* using the built in development server (cassini), it really is garbage, so switch to IIS Express.

Comment: Roundabout way of saying no, its not possible, eh?

Comment: Oh no actually it totally possible, there are numerous articles on the internet and questions that have valid answer on this website.  It would probably in your best interest to delete this question and use Stack Overflows search functionality, before asking a duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Forms Authentication With Only UserName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197357/asp-net-forms-authentication-with-only-username)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response, Chintana.  Unfortunately, that only returns me "".  I have also tried  Request.ServerVariables["logon_user"] and User.Identity.Name.  I am going to look into switching to windows authentication, as that seems the sure-fire why to get this to work.

Comment: That's very interesting.. usually the username will be blank only for anonymous users. But in your case, the user is authenticated via forms authentication handler.. Anyway; sorry I couldn't help you buddy .. hope for you to have better luck with windows auth